# Not able to get my default constructor method to read my variables in my class

Tags: java, constructor

I don't know why my default constructor in my Date class does not properly read the inputs that were sent to it from the DateTester class. I have to have a default constructor, a constructor with 3 inputs (day, month, and year), and mutator and accessor functions.

My Date Class code:

```
public class Date {
    private int day, month, year;
    public String checked = "";

    public void setDay(int d) {
        day = d;
    }
    public int getDay() {
        return day;
    }

    public void setMonth(int m) {
        month = m;
    }
    public int getMonth() {
        return month;
    }

    public void setYear(int y) {
        year = y;
    }
    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }
    public String getChecked() {
        return checked;
    }
    public Date() {
        day = getDay();
        month = getMonth();
        year = getYear();
        if ( year > 0 && month > 0 && month < 13 && day > 0 && day < 32) {  
            checked = "valid";
        }
        else {
            checked = "invalid";
        }
    }
    public Date(int day, int month, int year) {
        this.day = day;
        this.month = month;
        this.year = year;

    }
}
```

And my DateTester code:

```
public class DateTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        Date test = new Date();
        test.setDay(29);
        test.setMonth(2);
        test.setYear(2000);


        Date test2 = new Date();
        test2.setDay(29);
        test2.setMonth(2);
        test2.setYear(2016);

        System.out.println("The date is " + test.getMonth() + "/" + test.getDay() + "/" + test.getYear() + " and it is " + test.getChecked() + "!");
        System.out.println("The date is " + test2.getMonth() + "/" + test2.getDay() + "/" + test2.getYear() + " and it is " + test2.getChecked() + "!");
    }

}
```

Comment: And what do your print statements output currently? Also there is already a `Date` class in java so you might be getting mixed up with your custom one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A non-default constructor always implicitly calls the default constructor first (the default constructor calls `super()` first) if no other constructor is called by you explicitly.

So your validity-check already took place before values are set in the non-default constructor, so you end up with year, month and day being set but the validity being `false` because you checked against zeros.

You can change the code to make it work:

```
public Date() {
    this(0, 0, 0);
}

public Date(int day, int month, int year) {
    this.day = day;
    this.month = month;
    this.year = year;

    if ( year > 0 && month > 0 && month < 13 && day > 0 && day < 32) {  
        checked = "valid";
    }
    else {
        checked = "invalid";
    }
}
```

BTW: Your validity check sees e.g. Feb 30 as valid.

Comment: The professor asked only for basic day checks and not leap years or leap days, just to assume all months have 31 days.

Comment: Where was the OP using a non-default constructor to create objects of class Date?

Comment: @cosimo193 You're right. I missed that by focusing on the problems with the constructor. So in addition to the change I showed, the vailidty-check should be put into its own method that is called in every `set`-method (or make the whole thing immutable by removing the `set`-methods altogether.

Answer (score 0):

When the Date() constructor is called, the day, month and year fields' contents are undefined (possibly, I can't remember whether Java promises to initialise variables or not but, if it does, it's probably to zero), therefore the calls to getDay() etc in that constructor are going to use undefined, or zero values when calculating "checked".

In other words, the values you're passing the object in the setDay(), setMonth() etc calls are done AFTER the checks you're expecting it to do in the constructor.

I'm not really sure what you're trying to achieve but, if it's validating the date, you need to either pass the values in to the constructor, or have a separate isValid() function, or have each of the setter functions update the validity when a new field is added.

Answer (score 0):

With help from here I was able to get it all in working order and now code works.
My updated code is below.

My Date class code:

```
public class Date {
    public int day, month, year;
    public String checked = "";

    public Date() {
        this(0, 0, 0);
    }
    public Date(int day, int month, int year) {
        this.day = day;
        this.month = month;
        this.year = year;

    }
    public String isValid() {
        if ( year > 0 && month > 0 && month < 13 && day > 0 && day < 32) {  
            return "valid";
        }
        else {
            return "invalid";
        }
    }
}
```

And my DateTester code:

```
public class DateTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        Date test = new Date();
        test.day = 29;
        test.month = 2;
        test.year = 2000;


        Date test2 = new Date();
        test2.day = 40;
        test2.month = 2;
        test2.year = 2016;

        System.out.println("The date is " + test.month + "/" + test.day + "/" + test.year + " and it is " + test.isValid() + "!");
        System.out.println("The date is " + test2.month + "/" + test2.day + "/" + test2.year + " and it is " + test2.isValid() + "!");
    }
}
```

Comment: FWIW a function called "isValid()" would normally return a Bool then you'd make the decision on how to represent that once you've got the result. In this case your isVaild function would just need "return (year > 0 && month > 0 && month < 13 && day > 0 && day < 32);" and your test class would print "valid" or "invalid" based on that result.